# Handling informative NaN values

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I was wondering if there is any standard or recommendable way for handling informative NaN values, for example with respect to computing distances.

For informative NaN values, I mean NaN values that do not represent missing values, but values that are not numeric for an otherwise numerical feature.

For example, in a sociology study it could be reasonable to consider the age of the oldest child as a feature (and the second-oldest, etc.) and there a non-numerical value could reflect not a missing (unknown) value, but the fact that there is no child of that rank.

I'm aware of the "average" method by [Dixon 1979](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4310090), and the "penalized dissimilarity measure" by [Datta et al. 2016](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167865516301568), but these consider d(NaN,x)=d(NaN,NaN) (where x is a finite numerical value), but in the case of informative NaN values, I think it should be 0<d(NaN,NaN)<d(NaN,x).

Maybe d(NaN,NaN) and d(NaN,x) could be set based on some percentile value from the empirical distribution of pairwise distances obtained from the samples with a numerical value for that feature.

I'm not interested in imputation procedures since I don't want to artificially introduce correlations among features.